# pyqt4 python QLabel show when push button clicked

Tags: python, pyqt4

What i am trying to achieve is when user pressed push button, i want to show initially hidden QLabel. However, on that push button i have assigned a heavy duty scanning which takes about 2-3 minutes drive scanning. The QLabel is only appeared after scanning is finish, how do i make it appear once button is clicked and not after everything is done.

The codes

```
self.label_3.hide()
...
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._btn_cb)
...    
def _btn_cb(self):
    self.label_3.show() # here is the show code
    for filename in find_files("C://images//", '*.png'): # took roughly 2-3 minutes
        print filename
```

I am very new to python, thank you for assisting me

Comment: Why do you ask question and delete it? It's annoying I wrote an answer and you deleted the question!!! >< !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a call to

```
QApplication.instance().processEvents()
```

Just after you call `.show()` on your label. This will force Qt to process events in your queue (showing the label) before it moves on to the rest of the code.

Make sure you import `QApplication` from `QtGui` at the start of your code.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
```